# iPhone 14 hardware device type (identifier)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Does anyone already have **identifiers** for **iPhone 14/14 Plus/14 Pro/14 Pro Max**?

Currently don't have access to the Xcode-Beta to find them, so probably somebody has them already.

(14 Pro is mostly like **iPhone15,2** and 14 Pro Max is **iPhone15,3**, but not sure..)

Looked some articles and news, as well as Google, but no info.

UPD from Xcode:

- 14 > iPhone14,7
- 14 Plus > iPhone14,8
- 14 Pro > iPhone15,2
- 14 Pro Max > iPhone15,3

Answer (score 0):

there are no known identifiers as of now at the time of writing.

You can download Xcode from here:
[Download Xcode 14 Release Candidate Xip](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14_Release_Candidate/Xcode_14_Release_Candidate.xip), If you believe there are identifiers.

Comment: Nope, they are already there :-) Have downloaded, there are already all new iPhones and "SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER" works well..

Comment: I had mentioned at the time of writing. I don't have the identifiers in my Xcode beta at that time.